# JSF with CDI dataTable var is empty

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, cdi

I'm trying to loop over a list and print out some properties using a JSF dataTable as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
        <h:dataTable value="#{clubAdministrationController.members()}" var="member">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Leden" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Voornaam" />
                </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{member.firstName}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Achternaam" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{member.lastName}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputLink id="bewerklid#{member.username}" value="bewerklid/#{member.username}">Wijzig</h:outputLink>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
</html>
```

and I get this result:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Leden</th></tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Voornaam</th>
      <th scope="col">Achternaam</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="j_idt12:0:bewerklid" name="j_idt12:0:bewerklid" href="bewerklid/">Wijzig</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="j_idt12:1:bewerklid" name="j_idt12:1:bewerklid" href="bewerklid/">Wijzig</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The dataTable iterates the correct amount of times because I have 2 members, but all fields are empty.
When I debug the Java, the members() method returns a list with correctly filled instances and when I print out the values directly the correct values are printed.

```
#{clubAdministrationController.members().get(0).firstName} <!--displays values correctly  -->
```

When I print out the class name of the member var I get Member$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy

```
#{member['class'].simpleName} <!-- prints Member$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy -->
```

I think this suggests that something is going wrong with the dependency injection. I'm using CDI and I know that Weld is a CDI-implementation, and that CDI doesn't inject the actual class, but a proxy-class. I guess a proxy-class is instantiated but the fields must somehow still be copied from the source instance.

I just started learning JSF and CDI, so my question is "what do I have to change to make the dataTable display my Members?"

This is my ClubAdministrationController, when I debug it, the list is filled with my two members:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ClubAdministrationController {
  @Inject
  private MemberDao memberDao;
  public List<Member> members() {
    List<Member> members = memberDao.getMembers();
    return members;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant code of `clubAdministrationController` managed bean.

Comment: Why are you writing code differently from what the official Java EE / JSF tutorial and a sane JSF book tries to show you? E.g. method expression instead of value expression and business logic in getter method and using a render time variable in ID attribute. What resources exactly are you using to learn JSF?

Comment: @BalusC I'm writing code differently because I'M JUST STARTED LEARNING JSF AND CDI. Enlighten me, what is wrong with method expression? And where is my logic supposed to go? The view? The model? Or should it stay in the controller? And how should I make my HTML id predictable and unique? As resources, I'm using the internet, I used a Jboss example as a base project and I'm trying to understand it and adjust it to my needs, furthermore I'm using the JSF API's,Stackoverflow and Google. Do you approve? Despite your rep, you fail in making a constructive comment, yet 3 upvotes. Interesting.

Comment: @Tweepak You should get yourself a Book about JSF. Learing by googling is *bad*, because Google will only provide you the information you are explicit searching for. A Book will provide you background information and details around everything which you might not search for, because you don't even know it exists. Then, when you have build up a solid foundation of knowledge, you can start to dig into dedicated topics using other sources. Also a book is dedicated to a certain Version ("JSF 2.2") - online you will find examples throughout all versions and most likely  end up mixing them...

Comment: I asked it so I can review your learning resources and if necessary contact its author about the mistakes. But if you were just shooting around in the dark all by yourself, then there's indeed a little I can do (and my comment should implicitly hint that you'd really better learn JSF by a decent tutorial/book). Regardless, I recommend you to use our JSF wiki page as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info Good luck and you're always welcome to ask questions not asked before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `member` is a Weld-Proxy you seem to have a class that is `@Named` **member** somewhere. (implicit or explicit)

Your data table is now iterating over the correct `list` (therefore resulting in the correct row count), but always refering to a named class, which does not have the proper values. Most Likely, you have a certain Annotation on your `Member.class`, which then causes a named WeldProxy (which is empty) to be generated, when you use the el-expression `#{member}`

(this expression will win against the datatable var `member`)

Here, you are refering to the `instance of member` inside the list `member()`:

```
#{clubAdministrationController.members().get(0).firstName} <!--displays values correctly  -->
```

Here you are refering to the named weld-proxy `#{member}` - as the class-attribute shows:

```
#{member['class'].simpleName} <!-- prints Member$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy -->
```

Changing your `var="member"` to `var="m"` and use `m.firstName` should solve your problem.

To tell you what's wrong with your `Member.class`, you should include that Code as well.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly my problem!